# Let me know the way you pick up key from value in ruby

Tags: ruby

Now I wrote code on rails because there has to pick up key from value. 
But my code is not smart way I think like following.

```
TYPE = {
  1 => "A", 2 => "B", 3 => "C", 4 => "D"
}

def get_key_from_value(val)
  TYPE.each do |k,v|
    if v==val
      return k
    end
  end
  nil
end 

puts get_key_from_value "B" #=> 2
```

So please let me know your smartest way that how pick the key of Ruby's Hash object using value.

Comment: What if there are multiple keys with the same value, which one do you want?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev smth like `h.map {|k, v| k if v === 4} - [nil]`

Comment: `h.reject {|k, v| v != 4}.keys` does the trick as well.

Comment: Using `reject` is cool. I didn't think the case that multiple keys have same value. So, in my case, coming first key is ok, but If It want to adjust all case, map/reject (return as array) is good way I think. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 3):

Just use [Hash#key](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-key) method:

```
h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
h.key(4) # => :d
```

The same with your example:

```
h = {1=>"A", 2=>"B", 3=>"C", 4=>"D"}
h.key("D") # => 4
```

Comment: There might be a pitfall if a hash contains same values for different keys. In such a case only the first occurence will be returned. If there is a need to return all of them: `h.map {|k, v| k if v === 4} - [nil]`.

Comment: Would you please re-read my comment carefully: “…if a hash contains **same values** for **different keys**.”

Comment: Thank you for your advice hck, I should know that and I had to use `key` method first. Although I wrote before, mudasobwa's way is coolest, I think! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use [Hash.invert](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-invert):

```
TYPE = {
  1 => "A", 2 => "B", 3 => "C", 4 => "D"
}

TYPE_INVERT = TYPE.invert #you'll probably want a better name than this

puts TYPE_INVERT['B'] #=> 2
```

You’ll need to be careful if your hash has multiple keys all with the same value, as you’ll only get one of them in the inverted hash.

Comment: Use `invert` if you are doing this repeatedly. It would be significantly faster.

Comment: Which one is faster Using `map`/`reject` method or `invert`.

Comment: `invert` meas, I think, keep the inverted hash... Oh It sounds waste.